# Excel - Split by `;` in each cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vba

I would like to split these texts into cells in excel:

```
Hello-HOW-are-YOU-DOING-!
This-is-not-my-name-.
Random-People-are-looking-?
No-!
```

It should basically look like that:

[image]

At the moment I am using this formula, which gives me just the first split:

```
=LEFT(Export!A2;FIND("-";Export!A2)-1)
```

Any recommendations how I can do the split automatically for each `-`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Excel has a functionality for that: "split cell content". No? (Not sure about the name in English Excel right now.)

Comment: Alternatively, create a code module that delivers a VBA function that uses the VBA split function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199553/split-a-cell-into-varying-numbers-of-cells-excel showns a quite similar usecase.

Comment: Use Google Sheets ;)  [SPLIT function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With data in **B1;** in **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do this...

```
=MID($A2,FIND(B2,$A2)+LEN(B2)+1,FIND("-",$A2,FIND(B2,$A2)+LEN(B2)+1)-(FIND(B2,$A2)+LEN(B2)+1))
```

in cell D onwards since you already have

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)
```

for the first cell

Answer (score 0):

In Excel O365 with spilling this can now be done through:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

And from Excel 2013 onwards you could have still used `FILTERXML` but with `INDEX` and drag to the right:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),COLUMN(A1))
```